# Entity Framework - Stack Overflow Exception caused by static columns

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am running a Linq to SQL query in Entity Framework and it is giving me a StackOverflowException.  So I thought, this has to be the perfect website to ask this question.  But I see two other questions here about a StackOverflowException in Entity Framework and they got no answers.  Anyway, I'll give this a try.  My query was working, but I want to insert some spacer columns that will be loaded into my Telerik Spreadsheet control.  My search on StackOverflow told me how to enter static columns in my query and now every time I try to run it I get the a StackOverflowException.  Below is a sample of my query.  Can you tell me how to correct this?  If I remove the Spacer_1 column the error goes away, but I need a spacer column.

```
        using (var context = new MyEntities())
        {
            var query = context.MyTable
                .Where(o => o.id == idValue)
                .Select(o => new {
                    o.RealColumn1,
                    o.RealColumn2,
                    o.RealColumn3,
                    Spacer_1 = "",
                    o.RealColumn4,
                    o.RealColumn5
                });

            var list = query.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: The code you show here can't throw a stack overflow. Are you sure you are looking at the right method?

Comment: Yes.  The last line, query.ToList(), throws the StackOverFlow exception.

Comment: It is very strange behavior. But you can simply exclude `Spacer_1` from query and then make additional `Select` (after `ToList` call), where you, unfortunately, should copy-paste plain properties and add `Spacer_1 = ""`